# How to get current user's phone number

Tags: users, contact

I'm trying that :

```
<?php $phone = get_user_meta($current_user->ID,'phone_number',true); echo $phone; ?>
```

But it's not working

Comment: What have you tried regarding to debugging it ? Have you e.g. verified the input?

Comment: **1.** Check if phone number is entered to user profile  **2.** Check if phone number is in database  **3.** Check if your `meta_key` is correct  **4.** `Echo` user ID to make sure it exists and is correct  **5.** Write the phone number down and if page has loaded, open dev window, select source code, press `ctr+F` and type in your number - maybe you just echoed it to hidden element or it's just hard to see

Comment: "Not working" is simply not enough information. Do you have debugging enabled? Do you get any errors? Are you sure `$current_user` is a valid user object and in scope? Is the field name definitely `phone_number`?

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
  // number 9 will be user ID
  $all_meta_for_user = get_user_meta( 9 );
  print_r( $all_meta_for_user );

// find the key that you want
Array ( 
    [first_name] => Array ( [0] => Tom ) 
    [last_name] => Array ( [0] => Auger) 
    [nickname] => Array ( [0] => tomauger ) 
    [description] => etc.... 
)

// store it in a variable 
$last_name = $all_meta_for_user['last_name'][0];

// display it 
echo $last_name;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are not looping all users and only want to get current user `phone_number` meta then you can try the below.

```
$current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
$phone = get_user_meta($current_user_id,'phone_number',true);
echo $phone;
```

**NOTE**: This will work only for logged in user.

Also Check `phone_number` meta_key. By default wordpress doesn't have such meta key I guess.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress has a shortcut for getting the current user ID, which it sounds like you need-- [`get_current_user_id()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_user_id). Using that you should be able to get the information you need. The following is a proof of concept block of code that will check for the return values of the functions and apply some conditional logic in case you need to:

```
$uid = get_current_user_id();
if (!empty($uid)) {
  $phone = get_user_meta($uid,'phone_number',true); 
  if (!empty($phone)) {
    echo $phone;
  } else {
    echo 'User does not have a phone number stored in the database';
  }
} else {
  echo 'User is not logged in';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $phone = get_user_meta($current_user->ID,'phone',true); echo $phone;?>
```

it was "phone" and not "phone_number"

Answer (score 0):

```
$phone = get_user_meta($user_id, 'billing_phone', true);
echo $phone;
```